# I am needing to combine all data from Column F separated by a "," if Columns A and B Match

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am needing to combine all data from Column F separated by a "," if Columns D matches column A.

I know it can be done but I accidentally deleted the formula late last night when I was working late when I finally figured it out and now, I can't remember what I did.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: are you saying that the result is either all of column F or nothing? ... it is unclear what you are trying to do

Comment: Column F is the data I want to combine into column G. I want to separate by whats in column A. 10-000 will be on G2 and 10-0003 will be on G6. I wanted to compare Columns A and D and if they match then any items in Column F will combine into G separated by a ",". This will repeat going down the document.

Comment: Did you use Office 365? If yes you can use TEXTJION function.

Answer (score 1):

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,REPT(F1:F7,A1:A7=D1:D7))
```

Where `REPT` uses the BOOLEAN of `A1:A7=D1:D7` to repeat `F1:F7`. If TRUE it repeats the value one time, if false it repeats it 0 times. These values (only the TRUEs are joined separated by a delimiter using `TEXTJOIN`

Or:

```
=ARRAYTOTEXT(FILTER(F1:F7,A1:A7=D1:D7))
```

Where `FILTER` uses the same logic as explained above and `ARRAYTOTEXT` joins the result comma separated.